# contract first soap web service in grails

Tags: web-services, grails, soap, grails-plugin

What is the best way to writing contract first SOAP web service in a grails application? I've found there are two plugin available to write contract first webservice 1. Grails Metro Plugin 2. Grails SpringWS plugin.

But I'm not sure which is best to use for contract first webservice

Answer (score 1):

The Grails SpringWS plugin is no longer supported by the author, and no one has stepped up to take over support.  If it works for you as is, it works quite well.  Once you need to customize or there is a bug, you're on your own.

I ended up using SpringWS and just importing the dependencies manually.  Here is my dependencies section in BuildConfig.groovy:

```
    dependencies {
    runtime('org.springframework.ws:spring-ws:2.0.3.RELEASE')
    runtime('org.springframework.ws:spring-ws-core:2.0.3.RELEASE')
    runtime('org.springframework.ws:spring-ws-security:2.0.3.RELEASE')
    runtime('org.springframework.ws:spring-ws-support:2.0.3.RELEASE')
    runtime('org.springframework.ws:spring-xml:2.0.3.RELEASE')
    runtime('com.sun.xml.wsit:wsit-rt:1.1')
    runtime('commons-httpclient:commons-httpclient:3.0.1')
    test('com.github.robfletcher:betamax:1.0')
    }
```

And then define a client this way:

```
import org.springframework.ws.transport.http.CommonsHttpMessageSender


beans = {
    myMarshaller(org.springframework.oxm.jaxb.Jaxb2Marshaller) {
        contextPath = "com.the.jaxb.beans.to.marshall"
    }
wss4jSecurityInterceptor(org.springframework.ws.soap.security.wss4j.Wss4jSecurityInterceptor) {
        securementActions = "UsernameToken"
        securementPasswordType = "PasswordText"
    }

    myInterfaceTemplate(org.springframework.ws.client.core.WebServiceTemplate) {
        marshaller = ref("myMarshaller")
        unmarshaller = ref("myMarshaller")
        messageSender = { CommonsHttpMessageSender ms -> }
        interceptors = [wss4jSecurityInterceptor]
        defaultUri = ""
    }
}
```

So then you do

```
grails install-templates
```

And customize your web.xml:

```
    <servlet>
    <servlet-name>spring-ws</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>org.springframework.ws.transport.http.MessageDispatcherServlet</servlet-class>
    <init-param>
        <param-name>transformWsdlLocations</param-name>
        <param-value>true</param-value>
    </init-param>

    <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>

        </servlet>
        <servlet-mapping>
            <servlet-name>spring-ws</servlet-name>
            <url-pattern>/services/*</url-pattern>
        </servlet-mapping>
```

And I created a spring-ws-servlet.xml

```
<context:component-scan base-package="com.bean.base.package"/>

<bean id="myTypes" class="org.springframework.xml.xsd.SimpleXsdSchema">
    <property name="xsd" value="/WEB-INF/Types.xsd"/>
</bean>

<bean id="ContractFirstBeanName" class="org.springframework.ws.wsdl.wsdl11.SimpleWsdl11Definition"
      p:wsdl="/WEB-INF/ContractFirstBeanName.wsdl"/>

<bean class="org.springframework.ws.transport.http.XsdSchemaHandlerAdapter"/>

<bean id="outputMarshaller" class="org.springframework.oxm.jaxb.Jaxb2Marshaller"
      p:contextPath="com.output.beans"/>

<bean class="org.springframework.ws.server.endpoint.mapping.PayloadRootAnnotationMethodEndpointMapping">
    <property name="interceptors">
        <list>
            <bean id="loggingInterceptor"
                  class="org.springframework.ws.server.endpoint.interceptor.PayloadLoggingInterceptor">
                <property name="logRequest" value="true"/>
                <property name="logResponse" value="true"/>
            </bean>
            <ref local="wsSecurityInterceptor"/>
        </list>
    </property>
</bean>

<bean class="org.springframework.ws.transport.http.WsdlDefinitionHandlerAdapter">
    <property name="transformLocations" value="true"/>
</bean>

<bean class="org.springframework.ws.transport.http.WebServiceMessageReceiverHandlerAdapter">
    <property name="messageFactory">
        <bean class="org.springframework.ws.soap.saaj.SaajSoapMessageFactory"/>
    </property>
</bean>

<bean class="org.springframework.ws.server.endpoint.adapter.GenericMarshallingMethodEndpointAdapter">
    <constructor-arg ref="outputMarshaller" index="0"/>
</bean>
<bean id="wsSecurityInterceptor"
      class="org.springframework.ws.soap.security.xwss.XwsSecurityInterceptor">
    <property name="policyConfiguration" value="/WEB-INF/securityPolicy.xml"/>
    <property name="callbackHandlers">
        <list>
            <ref bean="springWSSecurityHandler"/>
        </list>
    </property>
</bean>
<bean id="springWSSecurityHandler"
      class="org.springframework.ws.soap.security.xwss.callback.SpringPlainTextPasswordValidationCallbackHandler">
    <property name="authenticationManager" ref="authenticationManager"/>
</bean>
```

Now this will give you Spring WS contract first end points, in Grails.

Answer (score 0):

Fairly old post, but might help others.

In addition to Rob's post:

Instead of installing the templates to be able to modify web.xml, you can also handle adding the MessageDispatcher servlet and its mapping dynamically in scripts/_Events.groovy:

```
eventWebXmlEnd = { String tmpfile ->
    GPathResult root = new XmlSlurper().parse(webXmlFile)
    GPathResult servlets = root.servlet
    servlets[servlets.size() - 1] + {
       'servlet' {
           'display-name'("web-services")
           'servlet-name'("web-services")
           'servlet-class'("org.springframework.ws.transport.http.MessageDispatcherServlet")
       }
    }
    def servletMappings = root.'servlet-mapping'
    servletMappings[servletMappings.size() - 1] + {
       'servlet-mapping' {
           'servlet-name'("web-services")
           'url-pattern'("/services/*")
       }
    }
    // update web.xml content
    webXmlFile.text = new StreamingMarkupBuilder().bind {
       mkp.declareNamespace("":"http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee")
       mkp.yield(root)
    }
}
```